# Application use with cascading dropdowns and Oracle DB

Tags: 2010, application-pages, oracle

I have a request to build a dashboard with CRUD for Oracle. I have tested this wit BCS and using an XML file which works.. To achieve this I have manually added an xml file (lightening Tools) in the CA and created an External Content Type all without VS.

As part of the POC an additional and more complex requirements is now needed.

A page with cascading dropdowns is needed, depending on choices the next dropdowns get dynamically built form a Oracle table(s).

Then when last selection gets made a sql query is built (from the dropdowns) and executed against the Oracle DB, probably through a parameter. The results are then displayed lower in the page.

SQL query will probably include joins etc.

I’ve have a lot of issues connecting with Oracle as SPD does not support it. However I think the above requirements have magnified the complications ten-fold and wondering if it’s all possible using SPD/XML Model/Infopath ?

Should this be done in VS or is the above scenario not a good application for SharePoint?

Thanks